# SQL -- percentage of each option in lookup field

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I am working with a look up field in Microsoft Access and I would like to show what percentage of the total each of the field's options make up. For instance, if there are 300 rows having option "A" is the lookup field and if there are 950 rows in total, I want the query to return 300/950*100 (or even just 300/950). I know how to use a query to get the number of counts, but I have not been able to figure out how to divide the counts by the number of rows (note: I don't want to enter the number of rows manually, I want the query to calculate it)
I would like the table to have two columns: one listing all the options in the field in question, the other listing the associated percentages.

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't yet showed us what you've tried, or what the schema of your table looks like. That makes answering your question very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`SELECT Option, Count(*)/(SELECT Count(*) FROM table WHERE NOT Option IS NULL)*100 AS Pct
FROM table
GROUP BY Option HAVING NOT Option IS NULL;`

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about grouping the denominator by Option of another Field? I have two look up fields that I am grouping by, and I am calculating the relative count of the options of field 1. I would like the denominator to be different for each option of field 2. (e.g. if field 1's option A has 120 rows and if field 2's option B has 20 rows such that their option in field 2 is A, I would the query to return 20/120. Thank you!

Comment: Huh? You better edit question to post sample raw data and desired output.